# Convert ISO 8601 time format to UNIX timestamp (epoch) and back again without losing fractional seconds?

Tags: python, timestamp

Python methods to convert ISO 8601 time format to UNIX timestamp (epoch) and back again without losing fractional seconds?

I found several examples, but all the examples seem to drop the fractional seconds at some point in the conversion.  Example below...

The issue seems to be the initial conversion to UNIX timestamp (epoch).  Code below.

```
def ISO8601ToEpoch(theString):

    from datetime import datetime
    import calendar

    return calendar.timegm(datetime.strptime(theString, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple())

def EpochToISO8601(theEpoch):

    from datetime import datetime

    return datetime.fromtimestamp(theEpoch).isoformat()

#

print 'Original Time {0}'.format('2018-04-27T04:19:51.050937')

theTime=ISO8601ToEpoch('2018-04-27T04:19:51.050937')
print 'Time {0}'.format(theTime)

print 'Original Time {0}'.format(EpochToISO8601(theTime)
```

This results as...

Original Time 2018-04-27T04:19:51.050937
Time 1524802791
Original Time 2018-04-27T04:19:51

Is there a way to get timetuple to not hack the fractional seconds?

Comment: Why are you going through `timetuple` (and `calendar.timegm`) instead of just using the `datetime` object in the first place?

Comment: The Unix timestamp is defined in integral seconds, you can't convert to it without losing the fractional seconds. Unless you create your own equivalent definition using real numbers.

Comment: @MarkRansom No, "Unix timestamp" isn't actually defined as integral. `time_t` is, but POSIX defines at least two other timestamp types that have sub-second fields, that are used as more precise timestamps all over the place in Linux and macOS. That's why Python's `datetime.timestamp()` and `datetime.fromtimestamp` deal with floats whenever possible. (Of course the lower-level functions in `time` and `calendar` do not, because they're specifically wrapping `time_t` and `struct tm`.) The OP's code already makes use of that fact in one direction, and he works; he just didn't do it the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're converting a `datetime`—which understands microseconds—into a `timetuple`—which doesn't.<sup>1</sup>

The obvious fix is just to not do that.

If you want to convert a `datetime` object to a timestamp, just use the [`timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method, the same way you already use the `fromtimestamp` classmethod to go the other way.

---

<sub>1. You *might* be able to trick a `timetuple` into holding a `float` instead of an `int` for seconds. But then you'd be breaking the invariants of the type. And, more importantly, defeating the entire purpose of the type, which is to be identical to a 1980s-style C `struct tm`. And likely also breaking the `timegm` function, which probably just calls the C function of the same name. (Most of the `time` module is a thin wrapper around C's `<time.h>`, as opposed to `datetime`, which is a friendly module designed for Python.) And then `timegm` is documented to return an integral type, so even if you got that far, it would all be for nothing.</sub>

Comment: I got these routines from google sources, trying to avoid some effort, but that obvious did not work great.  Can someone provide a code example of converting ISO to timestamp and back again?  Not a python guru, still learning.  Examples would be appreciated.

Comment: @Schorschi You already wrote one direction. For the opposite direction, just take the result of `strptime` and call `timetuple` on it. Also, if you look at the docs for the module instead of searching for random code and then trying to figure out what it does, you’ll find the answer a lot faster. Some modules aren’t documented that completely or that clearly, but most of the stdlib is. (Until you try to write a tkinter GUI…)

Comment: So, tinkering around with the timetuple, and time.mktime, I think I got what I need:

>>> import datetime as datetime
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> import time

>>> t=time.time()
>>> t
1478266530.573583

>>> i=datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t).isoformat()
>>> i
'2016-11-04T13:35:30.573583'

>>> d=dateutil.parser.parse(i)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 4, 13, 35, 30, 573583)
>>> s=(time.mktime(d.timetuple())*1e3+d.microsecond/1e3)/1e3
>>> s
1478266530.5735831

Comment: @Schorschi Why are you doing all that work instead of just calling `timestamp`?

Comment: Illustrate?  which what where?

Comment: @Schorschi I already gave you a link in the answer. If you’re using an older Python that doesn’t have that method, you can install a backport, or just copy and paste it from the 3.6 source (which is linked from the docs).

Comment: Is not timestamp() from datetime unique to python 3?

Comment: Ah! I have have not used backport yet... but understand the concept, will check it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is correct... but if not I am sure someone will point out what I missed.

```
>>> import datetime as datetime
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> import time

# Create a sample UNIX timestamp...
>>> t=time.time()
>>> t
1478266530.573583

# Convert the time stamp sample to ISO format...
>>> i=datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t).isoformat()
>>> i
'2016-11-04T13:35:30.573583'

# Convert ISO format to UNIX time stamp...
>>> d=dateutil.parser.parse(i)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 4, 13, 35, 30, 573583)
>>> s=(time.mktime(d.timetuple())*1e3+d.microsecond/1e3)/1e3
>>> s
1478266530.5735831
```

It is not a perfect conversion given the number of fractional digits of the resulting timestamp but close enough for my need.  I am sure the ISO format is a point of debate, but the format matches the typical format I expect to encounter, this is of course the lack of the 'Z' qualifier.

Comment: The `Z` means it's in the GMT timezone. Without either that `Z`, an offset, or a timezone ID, what you have is a "naive" datetime that's ambiguous (meaning it doesn't specify a timezone), but can be useful as a local time if only used locally.

Comment: Actually given the environment and coding standard, everything is UTC.  Which would 'mask' the issue, sure.  I have made a note regardless, when I get a bit of time, will swing back and address the Z issue, so it is explicitly qualified.